# getting error Cannot read property 'drawer' of undefined using Mini variant drawer of material-ui?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

**I am using [mini variant drawer](https://material-ui.com/components/drawers/#api) getting error in theme part.
when I was changing the styling of hook based component to class based component.
Error is TypeError: Cannot read property 'drawer' of undefined in appBar Styling.**

```
import React from 'react';
import { withTheme, withStyles } from '@material-ui/styles';
import clsx from 'clsx';
import Drawer from '@material-ui/core/Drawer';
import AppBar from '@material-ui/core/AppBar';
import Toolbar from '@material-ui/core/Toolbar';
import List from '@material-ui/core/List';
import CssBaseline from '@material-ui/core/CssBaseline';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import Divider from '@material-ui/core/Divider';
import IconButton from '@material-ui/core/IconButton';
import MenuIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Menu';
import ChevronLeftIcon from '@material-ui/icons/ChevronLeft';
import ChevronRightIcon from '@material-ui/icons/ChevronRight';
import ListItem from '@material-ui/core/ListItem';
import ListItemIcon from '@material-ui/core/ListItemIcon';
import ListItemText from '@material-ui/core/ListItemText';
import InboxIcon from '@material-ui/icons/MoveToInbox';
import MailIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Mail';

const drawerWidth = 240;
const useStyles = (theme) => ({
    root: {
        display: 'flex',
    },
    appBar: {
        zIndex: theme.zIndex.drawer + 1,
        transition: theme.transitions.create(['width', 'margin'], {
            easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
            duration: theme.transitions.duration.leavingScreen,
        }),
    },
    appBarShift: {
        marginLeft: drawerWidth,
        width: `calc(100% - ${drawerWidth}px)`,
        transition: theme.transitions.create(['width', 'margin'], {
            easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
            duration: theme.transitions.duration.enteringScreen,
        }),
    },
    menuButton: {
        marginRight: 36,
    },
    hide: {
        display: 'none',
    },
    drawer: {
        width: drawerWidth,
        flexShrink: 0,
        whiteSpace: 'nowrap',
    },
    drawerOpen: {
        width: drawerWidth,
        transition: theme.transitions.create('width', {
            easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
            duration: theme.transitions.duration.enteringScreen,
        }),
    },
    drawerClose: {
        transition: theme.transitions.create('width', {
            easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
            duration: theme.transitions.duration.leavingScreen,
        }),
        overflowX: 'hidden',
        width: theme.spacing(7) + 1,
        [theme.breakpoints.up('sm')]: {
            width: theme.spacing(9) + 1,
        },
    },
    toolbar: {
        display: 'flex',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'flex-end',
        padding: theme.spacing(0, 1),
        ...theme.mixins.toolbar,
    },
    content: {
        flexGrow: 1,
        padding: theme.spacing(3),
    },
});


class Admin extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { open: false };
    }

    handleDrawerOpen = () => {
        this.setState({ open: true });
    };

    handleDrawerClose = () => {
        this.setState({ open: false });
    };

    render() {
        const { classes } = this.props;
        return (
            <div className={classes.root}>
                <CssBaseline />
                <AppBar
                    position="fixed"
                    className={clsx(classes.appBar, {
                        [classes.appBarShift]: this.state.open,
                    })}
                >
                    <Toolbar>
                        <IconButton
                            color="inherit"
                            aria-label="open drawer"
                            onClick={this.handleDrawerOpen}
                            edge="start"
                            className={clsx(classes.menuButton, {
                                [classes.hide]: this.state.open,
                            })}
                        >
                            <MenuIcon />
                        </IconButton>
                        <Typography variant="h6" noWrap>
                            Mini variant drawer
          </Typography>
                    </Toolbar>
                </AppBar>
                <Drawer
                    variant="permanent"
                    className={clsx(classes.drawer, {
                        [classes.drawerOpen]: this.open,
                        [classes.drawerClose]: !this.state.open,
                    })}
                    classes={{
                        paper: clsx({
                            [classes.drawerOpen]: this.state.open,
                            [classes.drawerClose]: !this.state.open,
                        }),
                    }}
                    open={this.state.open}
                >
                    <div className={classes.toolbar}>
                        <IconButton onClick={this.handleDrawerClose}>
                            {this.theme.direction === 'rtl' ? <ChevronRightIcon /> : <ChevronLeftIcon />}
                        </IconButton>
                    </div>
                    <Divider />
                    <List>
                        {['Inbox', 'Starred', 'Send email', 'Drafts'].map((text, index) => (
                            <ListItem button key={text}>
                                <ListItemIcon>{index % 2 === 0 ? <InboxIcon /> : <MailIcon />}</ListItemIcon>
                                <ListItemText primary={text} />
                            </ListItem>
                        ))}
                    </List>
                    <Divider />
                    <List>
                        {['All mail', 'Trash', 'Spam'].map((text, index) => (
                            <ListItem button key={text}>
                                <ListItemIcon>{index % 2 === 0 ? <InboxIcon /> : <MailIcon />}</ListItemIcon>
                                <ListItemText primary={text} />
                            </ListItem>
                        ))}
                    </List>
                </Drawer>
                <main className={classes.content}>
                    <div className={classes.toolbar} />
                </main>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default withStyles(useStyles)(Admin);
```

Please tel the way to convert theme styling from hooks to class based component.

Answer (score 0):

I change like this:

```
const styles = theme => ({})
```